# Safely stop execution of sequential `await`s without handling thrown errors (js async/await conventions)

Tags: javascript, error-handling, async-await, try-catch

When I need to make two sequential api calls, I prefer for each of those functions to handle the errors that they are responsible for. I've been writing them like this:

```
class Api {
  static call(path) {
    ...
    return Promise.reject({ code: 400/422/... })
  }
}

async function closeMonkeyCages() {
  try {
    await Api.call('monkeys/close')
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code === 400) { alert('monkeys arent in the cages yet') }
    throw err
  }
}

async function feedTigers() {
  try {
    boom() // example ReferenceError
    await Api.call('tigers/feed')
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code === 422) { alert('you must pet them first') }
    throw err
  }
}

(async () => {
  try {
    await closeMonkeyCages()
    await feedTigers()
  } catch (err) {
    // do nothing, closeMonkeyCages + feedTigers should have already shown alerts
  }
})()
```

However, this code is dangerous. It swallows other errors. If I had a ReferenceError/TypeError/etc in my `try` block, I'd want it to be logged (ie: Sentry).

There are a few ways I can think of to solve this, but they all seem either messy, slightly wrong, or inflexible.

- async functions can return api exceptions without throwing, similar to the fetch api:

```
const resp = await closeMonkeyCages()
if (!resp.ok) return
await feedTigers()
```

- handle api exceptions (`alert()`) in my main block:

```
try {
  await closeMonkeyCages()
  await feedTigers()
} catch (err) {
  if (err?.code === 400) { // conditions that map to each error. messy. error-prone
    alert(getErrorMsg(err)) // hope this function handles all cases
  } else {
    // must have been another runtime error
    throw err
  }
}
```

- type-check the error:

```
try {
  await closeMonkeyCages()
  await feedTigers()
} catch (err) {
  if (err instanceof Error) {
    throw err
  }
  // do nothing, closeMonkeyCages + feedTigers should have already shown alerts
}
```

How would you keep your code clean and safe, while keeping errors scoped within the function where they are called?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should only handle the errors in your main program and not `alert` from the individual functions but then continue as nothing has happened - you still need `closeMonkeyCages` to throw an exception so that you never start feeding the tigers without the cages being closed. You may still keep the appropriate error messages in the respective functions though:

```
class ApiError extends Error {
  constructor(msg, cause) {
    super(msg);
    this.cause = cause;
  }
}

async function closeMonkeyCages() {
  try {
    await Api.call('monkeys/close')
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code === 400) throw new ApiError('monkeys arent in the cages yet', err)
    throw err
  }
}

async function feedTigers() {
  try {
    boom() // example ReferenceError
    await Api.call('tigers/feed')
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code === 422) throw new ApiError('you must pet them first', err)
    throw err
  }
}
```

```
try {
  await closeMonkeyCages()
  await feedTigers()
} catch (err) {
  if (err instanceof ApiError) {
    alert(err.message)
    console.log(`${err.message} caused by`, err.cause);
  } else {
    throw err
  }
}
```

This has nothing to do with `async`/`await`, it's exactly the same convention for error handling as in synchronous code.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your required logic flow correctly, you can `throw false` if you handle the 400 condition

The check if `err` is not `false` in the final catch

```
async function closeMonkeyCages() {
  try {
    await Api.call('monkeys/close')
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code === 400) { 
      alert('monkeys arent in the cages yet') 
      throw false
    }
    throw err
  }
}

async function feedTigers() {
  try {
    boom() // example ReferenceError
    await Api.call('tigers/feed')
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code === 422) { 
      alert('you must pet them first') 
      throw false
    }
    throw err
  }
}

(async () => {
  try {
    await closeMonkeyCages()
    await feedTigers()
  } catch (err) {
    if(err === false) {
      // do nothing, closeMonkeyCages + feedTigers should have already shown alerts
      return
    }
    // handle other errors
  }
})()
```

Comment: This could work, but most api calls also need a catchall, since network errors happen, and they usually don't need to be logged (perhaps I should have included that in my example). How would I distinguish that catchall from a RangeError/TypeError/ReferenceError/etc?

Comment: by checking the error itself?i.e the type of error

Comment: meaning... having a custom error class for api calls, and using `if (instanceof ApiError( { ... }` in every `catch` block in my project?

Comment: no, just the final one - maybe I don't understand the intended program flow as much as I thought